# SQL request how to return all the date before one date - FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made the following code :

```
(SELECT MAX("tn".DATE) 
FROM A.Test_Name "tn" 
WHERE "tn".Test_NAME = 1
AND "tn".Date <= '18Dec2022')
```

Which does take the max date, how can I do to select all the "tn" dates below 18Dec2022 ?

I did try to do :

```
(SELECT "tn".DATE
FROM A.Test_Name "tn" 
WHERE "tn".Test_NAME = 1
AND "tn".Date <= '18Dec2022')
```

but this does throw an error :

```
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I use this query to do a `JOIN`

```
JOIN A.Test_Name tn ON tn.Test_Name = 1 AND tn.DATE = 
(SELECT MAX("tn".DATE) 
FROM A.Test_Name "tn" 
WHERE "tn".Test_NAME = 1
AND "tn".Date <= '18Dec2022')
```

Comment: 1- get rid of these double quotes, they are unnecessary, 2-unless a query is a subquery you don't need to wrap it around parenthesis, 3 - `date` may be a reserved word for the RDBMs you are using, so use backticks around it 4- if the last query you are using is the real code,  a query can not start from a join, so you need an outer query for it, and you will need to add an alias to that query under the parenthesis.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the table structure (what is the real column name for 'DATE', and what is its data type - hopefully that *is* DATE?), sample data (including full date/time if not all midnight), and expected results for that data. With a valid name your second query should not get that error; it's unclear what you're trying to do with the third. The title says "all the date before one date", which the 2nd would do, but 3rd is looking for a single day? It's a bit confusing... see [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the analytic `RANK` function to find the maximum values (without having to query the table twice):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT tn.*,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tn."DATE") AS rnk
  FROM   A.Test_Name tn
  WHERE  tn.Test_Name =  1
  AND    tn."DATE"    <= DATE '2022-12-18'
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

*Note 1: Using quoted identifiers is generally considered bad practice as you have to use exactly the same case for the quoted identifiers; whereas if you use unquoted identifiers then you can use any case.*

*Note 2: However, `DATE` is a reserved word and if you are going to use it as an identifier then you must use a quoted identifier.*

Comment: Hey there, isn't `alias` mandatory for subqueries? Or Oracle does accept it without an alias? Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeCampos No, it is not mandatory (in Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like perhaps `DATE` is a keyword.  Try quoting it like other identifiers:

```
SELECT "tn"."date"
FROM A.Test_Name "tn" 
WHERE "tn".Test_NAME = 1
AND "tn"."date" <= '18Dec2022'
```